# How to dry-run scalatest?

Tags: sbt, scalatest

I marked test that took extremely long time to check with a special tag. I tried add tag to the ignored list, but scalacheck runs it regardless.

So I'd like to list all tests with specific tag or make a dry-run to see if tag exclusion option (`-l`) has any effect.

How should I do it?